# Set div width through a div above him

Tags: html, styles

i got a situation like this:

```
<div1> 
   <div2 style="width:50%"></div>
   <div3 style="width:50%"></div>
</div>
```

I want to override the style setting but I can't give a class to the div2 and div3. I would like to set the div2 at 65% and the div3 at 35%. Actually I can't modify the style, can't give a class and neither an id to div2 and div3, only to div1.

How could i make it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the style for div1, it's straightforward. Give an id to div1, such as canmodify, and use the following css

```
#canmodify div:nth-child(1) {width:65% !important;}
#canmodify div:nth-child(2) {width:35% !important;}
```

Comment: Instead, if i have the id on div above div1 how should i make ?
I mean 
`<div0 id="canmodify">
   <div1>
     <div2 style="width:50%"></div>  
     <div3 style="width:50%"></div>
  </div>
</div>`

Comment: You need to use structural selectors. In this case, you can use, for example, #canmodify > div > div:nth-child(1) {width:65% !important;}, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question isn't very clear... When you say you want to get div2 to 65%, do you mean his height or his width? If you're talking about his height, then just modify your divs' style:

```
    <div style="width:50% height:65%">
    <div style="width:50% height:35%">
```

If you're talking about the width, do you want to set their width to 65% of 50% and 35% of 50% or just to 65% and 35% of the div1's width? In the first case, replace 50% by respectively 32.5% for div2 and 17.5% for div3.  Finally, if you simply wanted to put div2 at 65% and div3 at 35% of div1's width, simply replace the 50% by the desired number, like so:

```
    <div1> 
          <div2 style="width:65%"></div>
          <div3 style="width:35%"></div>
    </div>
```

If I misunderstood the question or made any mistakes when typing it, please inform me of my errors.

Thanks!